# jQuery/JavaScript string replace a specific word and all characters after it

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, character

How can I remove spaces, a keyword, and everything after it? Here's what I'm looking for

```
var test = $('.replaceMe').attr('title').replace(/ /g, '');

<a class="replaceMe" href="#" title="Replace By Everything After It">haha</a>
```

resulting in:

```
test = Replace;
```

---

UPDATE:

The keyword is a yet-to-be-determined word that will be included in all titles. In this example, it is "By".

Both Roko and user1215106's answers work- in that they remove all the excess from the example, leaving Replace, but I failed to clarify that the phrase before the keyword (in this case, Replace) will vary and will have differing amounts of words.

For example:

```
title="Replace By Everything After It"

Result= Replace

title="All This Should Stay By Things That Should Go"

Result= AllThisShouldStay
```

Comment: what do you mean by "keyword"?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the first word of the title attribute as a string?

Comment: mvbl fst: clarified post to explain. Sime Vidas: kind of sort of, clarified above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/5qkvq/2/)**

```
var keyword = 'By';

var test = $('.replaceMe').attr('title').split(keyword)[0].replace(/ /g, '') ;
```

---

Or instead of having the `keyword` variable you can do:

```
var test = $('.replaceMe').attr('title').split('By')[0].replace(/ /g, '') ;
```

Comment: not quite, i'll elaborate above. the phrase before "by" (or whatever the keyword ends up being) varies.

Comment: @technopeasant so... (in your 2. example) your keyword is actually the word `By`, right?

Comment: @technopeasant :) there you go! I reedited my answer and the demo

Comment: @technopeasant so actually you were very close, you just missed this: `.split('By')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = $('.replaceMe').attr('title').replace(/\s+by\s.*/, '').replace(/\s+/. '');
```

Comment: same as Roko- not quite, i'll elaborate above. the phrase before "by" (or whatever the keyword ends up being) varies.

Answer (score 0):

Let `key` be the keyword you want to find.

```
escapedKey = key.replace(/([-$^&*()\/\\+?.\[\]{}|])/g, "\\$1");
$('.replaceMe').attr('title').replace(new RegExp(escapedKey + ".*"), "")
```

I tried to generalize for arbitrary keyword, but not yet tested for everything.